# How to judge if a file is the ".." file in Linux kernel programming?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, inode

I am working on Linux kernel programming which need to track the file(inode) path.

I know some functions such as S_ISDIR, S_ISLNK to judge if a file is a directory or soft link. But I don't know how to judge if a file(inode) is the ".." file, i.e., the file points to the parent directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no inode with name as '..'. When you access a file such as /etc/passwd, there is a process called path name lookup which translates each '/', 'etc' and 'passwd' to inodes. When it encounters '.' or '/' or '..' there is a special processing. For '.' and '/', it's kind of no-op and continues to use same inode. For '..' it goes back to fetch parent inode it had come from. This is explained very clearly in [Understanding the Linux Kernel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596005652) Chapter 12, Virtual File System. I strongly recommend going through it. Also see http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/filesystems/path-lookup.txt

Comment: To be specific I am writing a security model which will block the operation if it wants to follow either a symbolic link, or ".." under certain circumstance. I can tell if it wants to visit a slink using S_ISLNK(inode->i_mode), but how can I tell if it wants to visit ".."?

Thanks for your answer anyway, I'm new in this and your reference helped me a lot.

Comment: Then I guess you will have to update this part of pathname lookup:
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/namei.c#L1745
Note that this is VFS code and would affect all filesystems.